# URLs don't change for 404 and WordPress 404 page does not load

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have designed the 404 page for WordPress however whenever I try typing out an address like `www.homepage.com/gobblegobble` the URL stays the same and the page that is shown is my home page i.e. `www.homepage.com`.

Ideally, for these kind of random links I want the 404.php page to be shown. How do I change that?

My .htaccess file is in the htdocs/WordPress folder and is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
```

I have solved this by tweaking the permalinks *slaps forehead*. Sorry for the trouble caused.

Comment: And what status code do you get in response header?

Comment: How do I check the response header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the `404.php` file under the current theme's directory. WordPress will handle it, you don't need to change anything on `.htaccess`.

Comment: I had already done that. However, when trying any kind of gibberish URLs, I still get the home page. Is there any part of the wordpress code that calls the 404.php file when the address bar has an invalid URL? Because I may have accidentally changed that in the wordpress file.

Comment: @Ganesh: Are you sure the `404.php` is under ACTIVE theme's directory? WordPress will handle that automatically, I don't think you have messed with the core code, have you? If you have, do a `Re-install` from the `Dashboard->Update`. Read [Creating an Error 404 Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) for a close to complete explanation of WordPress error handling.

Comment: I haven't touched any of the code from the wp-admin folder if that was what you had meant by core code. The 404.php is under the active theme directory. I think it's a problem of linking the two files, if that makes any sense :(

Comment: Didn't touch it. I was only fiddling around in the theme files.

Comment: @Ganesh: If you go to `Appearance -> Editor`, then select the active theme on the right side and click on `Select` button, do you see a `404 Template` on the `Templates` list? Do you have this somewhere online?

Comment: I do see the 404 code but I do not see this same code loading; however when I tried the 404 for the subdomain sites, it had worked. My site is not online anywhere. I think since it is one page with no scalable changes in the future, I think I'll put in a manual 404 redirect. Thanks Shef!